# Linear Algebra Similarity Orbit

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. The similarity orbit of
$A$ is the collection of matrices of the form $SAS^{-1}$ where $S$
is an invertible matrix. Describe all the matrices $A$ so that the
similarity orbit of $A$ is $\{A\}$

So far I got that only the identity can satisfy the $SAS^{-1}$ and just want to be clear if I am missing out on any thing.

Answer (score 0):

The multiples of the identity also satisfy the same.  In fact, it is indeed true that the orbit of $A$ is $\{A\}$ if *and only if* $A = \lambda I$ for some scalar $\lambda$.